# why is my keywordLine in keywordFile not working?

Tags: python, file

I have to scan a file for keywords, however when I try to open up this file it stops at for keywordLine in keywordsFile: why does this happen?

def compute_tweets(tweets, keywords):

```
global unhappy, okay, satisfied, excited, good, happy, alright
timeZones = ()

try:
    keywordsFile = open(keywords, 'r', encoding='utf-8')

    unhappy = []
    okay = []
    alright = []
    satisfied = []
    excited = []
    good = []
    happy = []

    for keywordLine in keywordsFile:
        keywordLine = keywordLine.rstrip('\n')
        splitKeywordLine = keywordLine.split(',')
        if splitKeywordLine[1] == '1':
            unhappy.append(splitKeywordLine[0])
        elif splitKeywordLine[1] == '3':
            okay.append(splitKeywordLine[0])
        elif splitKeywordLine[1] == '4':
            alright.append(splitKeywordLine[0])
        elif splitKeywordLine[1] == '5':
            satisfied.append(splitKeywordLine[0])
        elif splitKeywordLine[1] == '7':
            excited.append(splitKeywordLine[0])
        elif splitKeywordLine[1] == '8':
            good.append(splitKeywordLine[0])
        else:
            happy.append(splitKeywordLine[0])

            keywordsFile.close()
except IOError:
    print('Error: File', keywords, "does not exist")
    print(timeZones)
```

Comment: What means "it stops"? If there is an error message show the full traceback as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: @MichaelButscher this is the error message: File "/Users/amit/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/sentiment_analysis.py", line 18, in compute_tweets
    for keywordLine in keywordsFile:
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

Comment: dedent your last line `keywordsFile.close()`, it should be outside the `for` loop

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.